# design patterns assignments

Tags: java, design-patterns

Is there any place to find multiple assignments for implementing design patterns( along with solutions ?)

My idea is to get the hands on in a proper way. I would like to implement those in Java. at the moment I just need basic design patterns , not J2EE patterns.

I'm actually looking for the complete application to be developed which uses most of the design patterns. (All design patterns in a single assignment)

Comment: [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1673841/examples-of-gof-design-patterns)

Comment: @Deepak : I'm actually looking for a type of assignment which has all the design patterns takes part. even though the following links are good , I'll check which link satisfy my need and accept the solution

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Build Me An Antfarm!!**

You want an assignment? I'll give you one. It's due Tuesday, February 22 at 9:00PM Pacific time. You are going to build me an antfarm, and you're going to use some common design patterns to do it.

This does not have EVERY design pattern, because that's just silly. It does, however, have enough that the interactions will be complex while being simple enough to implement quickly. Once this is done, we can look at adding in more features to our ant farm!

I will add requirements (with what revision they were added) as needs arise.

Here's the requirements:

**Functional Requirements**:

- A meadow can have many ant farms in them. For this assignment, only ever allow one meadow to take place.
- A meadow should be capable of spawning a logically unlimited number of antfarms.
- An antfarm should be comprised of a network of antfarm rooms.
- An antfarm should have rooms for spawning more ants.
- Ants should be able to battle other ants. When they do, the loser of the battle should die (it's antfarm can no longer command it), and the winner of the battle should get the attributes of the ant.
- An antfarm should only have one species of ant. Each species should have some kind of bonus to them. Perhaps they harvest food faster. Perhaps they have a higher chance to kill other ants.
- If a member of an ant colony kills the queen of another colony, the killer's queen should assume control of the dead queen's population of ants. all ants should now also have the attributes of both species of ant. (So if one species was strong, and the other species was efficient, now both populations are merged into a single population that is both strong and efficient.)
- Ants should have to rest every so often. When they do, they should consume food. An antfarm should be limited in capacity of how many ants can rest at a time based on the number of rooms (X amount per resting room).
- The simulation should end when, at the end of a tick, there is 1 or less active colonies/queens. This means you should spawn at least 2 colonies before your first tick.
- Rooms in the Antfarm should require a certain (probably large) number of worker-ticks to build. So, if it would take 1 worker 100 ticks to dig a room, it would take 50 workers 2 ticks, etc. But there should be a significant cost to building a room, since rooms determine how much you can rest. (This requirement added in spec revision 1.)

**Technical Requirements**: (Design patterns bolded)

- The Meadow class MUST be a **singleton**.
- An antfarm should be a built by building rooms into an antfarm. **(Builder pattern)**
- Drones and Warriors should only be created with the **factory pattern** by AntRooms, and Queens by the **factory pattern** by Meadows for purposes of a new colony.
- Use the **decorator pattern** to keep track of an ant's attributes.
- Antfarms should be **templated (using Java generics)** to hold any type of ant, and the antfarm should specify at runtime which type of ant it holds.
- The simulation should be tick-based. **(Mediator pattern)** Each tick, every ant (in a random order) should perform some action based on its surroundings. Drones should look for food, warriors should hunt enemies (or go back for food if hungry) and queens should spawn an egg.

**Interface requirements**:

The interface to the ant farm should be a command line interface with the following commands:

- `spawn X Y T` - should create a new colony at position X,Y of species T. The output should give an identifier for the colony so it can be controlled later.
- Example `spawn 14 -32 Killer` creates a colony of "Killer" ants at position x14 y-32.
- `give I R A` - should give the colony identified by I (at creation) resource R of amount A.
- Example `give 1 food 50` gives colony 1 50 food.
- Example `give 3 warrior 10` gives colony 3 10 warriors that spawn at colony 3's base.
- `tick [T]` - should perform T tick operations. For convience, allow T to not be specified, and simply tick once.
- Example `tick 10`
- Example `tick`
- `summary I` - should give a summary of colony I. A summary gives information about that colony.
- Example `summary 1` might give the following output:

Output:

```
    Species: Killer
    Workers: 14
    Warriors: 10
    Ant Kills: 18
    Colony kills: 2 (2:Pansy 4:Gatherer)
    Ticks alive: 143
    Status: Alive
```

- Example `summary 2` might give the following output:

Output:

```
    Species: Pansy
    Workers: 4
    Warriors: 0
    Ant Kills: 2
    Colony kills: 0
    Ticks Alive: 25
    Status: Killed by 1:Killer
```

If you run into any difficulty, post a comment about it. I'll try to give you some hints like blank classes, method headers, or just general ideas about how to make these design patterns interact with eachother.

Good luck, and **HAVE FUN**!!

Comment: For the record, I wrote this myself in about an hour. If anyone has suggestions for it, feel free to post them here and I'll consider putting them in! I'm definitely open to ideas on how to make this more fun and more educational at the same time.

Comment: In b4 "HERP DERP I'm looking for all design patterns in a single assignment because i don't understand that there are hundreds of deisign patterns many of which handle completely different and completely unrelated problems"

Comment: @ slifty You owe me a new keyboard! I'm sure we could squeeze in a few more hehehe. I figure these are the ones that are most common (at least in my experience) and should at least give him enough complication to keep him busy on design patterns until he has these. And, honestly, if an assignment for only 5 takes an hour to write, an assignment with 10 would probably take 3 or 4 to get all the kinks worked out. Using 20 (which... is too many for one program, honestly... time to split it up) would take far more time than I'm willing to spend!!

Comment: @srina Seeing as you've accepted this as a solution, I guess that means you accepted the due date as well? :) We'll see how you do! I hope you have a lot of fun and learn a lot!

Comment: @glowcoder Oh definitely -- I wasn't criticizing!  I was just preempting srinannapa's silly demands :)

Comment: @glowcoder.can you post the code so that it can handy for further reference.

Comment: @Deepak I expect the code for this will take between 10 to 20 hours to write, depending on the person's familiarity with design patterns and generics. I personally have not taken the time to write out the code, although I did draft some outlines of the classes of how I would solve it. My plan was (if OP actually does it) to review his code like I would for any other lead checking/peer review and give feedback based on that.

Answer (score 1):

http://www.allapplabs.com/java_design_patterns/java_design_patterns.htm
The above site caters to few design patterns and it also has loads of examples with solutions

Comment: I'm looking for all design patterns in a single assignment

Answer (score 0):

You can also take problems from the book "Head first design patterns". It has a lot of puzzle problems at the end of each chapter.

Comment: Let me know if you want a copy of that book.